# Check, on local machine only, if a workbook is open

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA function that check if a workbook is open. it goes like this:

```
Public Function IsWorkBookOpen(filename As String)
    Dim ff As Long, ErrNo As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    ff = FreeFile()
    Open filename For Input Lock Read As #ff
    Close ff
    ErrNo = Err
    On Error GoTo 0
    Select Case ErrNo
        Case 0:    IsWorkBookOpen = False
        Case 70:   IsWorkBookOpen = True
        Case Else: Error ErrNo
    End Select
End Function
```

I use it in a condition to check if the workbook is already open, if it is I close it, if it's not I open it. It works well but I have a little problem. This workbook is used by other excel files and this function returns true when it's open in onther machines on the network. i need it to check only if the file is open locally because I'm only reading it. Can someone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As long as your file share (Samba / CIFS) supports file locking, this should work.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand what you mean.I have a simple shared drive on a windows network. I don't know what you mean by file locking.

Comment: "windows network" == CIFS. "File locking" is the exact mechanism that "your" code is using to check if a workbook is open.  Windows network shares support file locking, so your code (correctly) indicates if **anyone** has the workbook open.

Comment: Am I correct in my understanding that you want to *change* this code to return `True` iff you have the workbook open locally?  If you want to change the semantics of this code, you should start by understanding it.  Basically, there is no easy/sane way to do what you ask.

Comment: Yes, i want the code to return true ONLY if the workbook is open locally. I mean, I don't care if it is open in other machines.

Comment: But I made a simple workaround with the "file lock" tip you gave me. I just made a condition with it. So if the file is locked, it will be opened as readonly, if it is not locked it will be opened normaly.

Comment: If Not FileLocked("myfile") Then
    Workbooks.Open "myfile"
Else
    Workbooks.Open "myfile", ReadOnly:=True
End If

Comment: I actually don't know if it makes sense at all, thinking about it.

Comment: Sorry, it was a dumb question. Just doing the else statement would solve my problem even with the original function. That's why too much hours straight don't do any good. :T Please remove this question if you feel like it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old question, but since no definitive solution was posted, I solved the problem by using the following code:

```
For Each Workbook In Application.Workbooks
    Debug.Print Workbook.Name
Next
```

This simple loop will print all file names that are open in your Excel application. This workaround should be enough to tell you if the desired file already exists or not.
Please take notice that, if only the file name isn't enough (considering that there could be multiple files with the same name saved on different locations), you could also apply the FullName property:

```
For Each Workbook In Application.Workbooks
    Debug.Print Workbook.FullName
Next
```